# Updated Unity project from 2020.2.1f to 2021.1.7: lighting is messed up, scenes are brighter

Tags: unity, shaders, lighting

I've updated my project from **2020.2.1f** to **2021.1.7** (also tried **2020.3.8**), and now my scenes are **much brighter** for some reason:
[image]

Any tips?

Current I use the standard pipeline I think, because the Render Pipeline Asset is set as None.

I have only one realtime directional light in the scene, and no Lighting Settings set in the Lighting window. The environment is the Default-Skybox.

Comment: You haven't shown us any of your scene, rendering, or lighting setup. We don't even know which rendering pipeline you're using. That's going to make it challenging to guess how your game is working and where the issue might be.

Comment: @DMGregory Sorry! I tried adding some info but I'm unsure what is helpful in this case so I think there is more to be stated.